# R count occurrences of x

Tags: r

I'm trying to count the NA values for each column of a data set, I'm able to get this information but I'm now trying to summarise it and place the information in a data frame.

Data set (segment) -

[image]

```
data_matrix = as.data.frame(matrix(0,nrow = 4, ncol=2))
colnames(data_matrix) = c("Number missing","Frequency")
data_matrix$`Number missing` = c(0,1,2,3) 

missing = sapply(segment, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))

# Missing output
# KJIS10 CSDF32  X   ASDF67 
#      0      0  3        2      

# What I'm trying to achieve
# Amount Missing Frequency
#              0         2
#              1         0
#              2         1
#              3         1
```

Amount missing being the number of missing pieces of data per column. No column has more than 3 pieces of data missing. How would I preform this sort of count?

Comment: `as.data.frame(table(AmountMissing))` that will give you frequency. If you want to do it with dplyr
`missing<‐data_matrix %>%
    group_by(AmountMissing) %>% 
count()`

Comment: @MichaelVine Almost gave the same comment. `table(missing)` gives the essential information the OP wants, but not in the format they want it in, probably most especially not listing those amounts for which `Frequency` would be 0

Comment: @duckmayr yes you are right, however,  this will give him afrequency count including NA or empty string and a starting point to figuring it out.

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible? Without `segment` the interesting part of the code is not runnable.

Comment: Amazing! Since I have a set number of rows I was able to just do this, data_matrix$Frequency = table(missing)